# Why does integrating scipy.multivariate_normal give incorrect probability?

Tags: scipy, probability, normal-distribution, numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate an independent bivariate normal distribution over a square region.  The numerical integration does not match a Monte Carlo simulation.  What's going wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

sigmaX = 0.5
sigmaY = 0.8
region = 1.0  # Region of interest is a unit square centered at the mean (0,0)

# Numerical integration for answer:
def pdf(x,y):
    return multivariate_normal.pdf([x,y], mean=[0,0], cov=[[sigmaX, 0], [0, sigmaY]])
probability, err = integrate.nquad(pdf, [[-region/2.0, region/2.0], [-region/2.0, region/2.0]])

# Monte Carlo simulation for answer:
simulations = 1_000_000
X = np.random.normal(scale=sigmaX, size=simulations)
Y = np.random.normal(scale=sigmaY, size=simulations)
hits = sum(1 for s in range(simulations) if ((abs(X[s]) < region/2.0) and (abs(Y[s]) < region/2.0)))/simulations

print(f'Numerical integration gives probability {probability:.1%}\n'
      f'Monte Carlo gives probability {hits:.1%}')
```

Output:

> Numerical integration gives probability 22.1%
>
> Monte Carlo gives probability 31.9%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagonals of the covariance matrix are the *variances*, while the `scale` argument of `np.random.normal` is the *standard deviation*.  One way to fix your calculation is to change the `cov` argument of the `pdf` function to

```
cov=[[sigmaX**2, 0], [0, sigmaY**2]]
```